# Cross elasticity of demand

Tags: microeconomics

If Q1=(P2)⅔
1. Determine the demand for good 1, when the price of good 2 is 8
2. Find the cross elasticity of demand for good 1, with respect to P2, when P2=2

Comment: What is your attempt to solve? And you may want to use MathJax -- https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. $P_2 = 8$, so $Q_1= 8^{2/3}=4$
2. To find the cross price elasticity, differentiate demand for good 1 with respect to $P_2$: $\frac{dQ_1}{dP_2}=\frac{2}{3}P_2^{-1/3}$
   When $P_2=2$, cross price elasticity is $\frac{2}{3}(2)^{-1/3}$

Hope you did post a question here after really thinking it through.